# Java : What is - public static<T> foo() {...}?

Tags: java, generics, static-methods

I saw a java function that looked something like this-

```
public static<T> foo() {...}
```

I know what generics are but can someone explain the  in this context? Who decides what T is equal to? Whats going on here?

EDIT: Can someone please show me an example of a function like this.

Comment: You mean like: public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key) in Collections? It's just a generic type, in this case if your key is a String, then your List has to be of elements that implement Comparable that can compare Strings. There's nothing deciding what T is equal to, it's just compile time checks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've missed the return type out, but apart from that it's a generic method. As with generic types, `T` stands in for any reference type (within bounds if given).

For methods, generic parameters are typically inferred by the compiler. In certain situations you might want to specify the generic arguments yourself, using a slightly peculiar syntax:

```
    List<String> strings = Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

In this case, the compiler could have inferred the type, but it's not always obvious whether the compiler can or can't. Note, the `<>` is after the dot. For syntactical reasons the type name or target object must always be specified.

It's possible to have generic constructors, but I've never seen one in the wild and the syntax gets worse.

I believe C++ and C# syntaxes place the generic types after the method/function name.

Comment: you rock. Behold, true java guru! /bows down/ :D

Answer (score 3):

The context is a generic method as opposed to a class. The variable `<T>` applies only to the call of the method..  The Collections class has a number of these; the class itself is not generic, but many of the methods are.

The compiler decides what T is equal to -- it equals whatever gets the types to work.  Sometimes this is easier then others.

For example, the method `static <T> Set<T> Collections.singleton(T o)` the type is defined in the parameter:

```
Collections.singleton(String T)
```

will return a `Set<String>`.

Sometimes the type is hard to define. For example sometimes there is not easily enough information to type `Collection.emptyList()`. In that case you can specify the type directly: `Collection.<String>emptyList()`.

Answer (score 1):

T it's the formal type parameter wich will be replaced by the actual type
argument used at the instantiation of the object.

For example, here is the List and Iterator definitios in package java.util:

```
public interface List<E>{
  void add(E x);
  Iterator<E> iterator();
}

public interface Iterator<E>{
  E next();
  boolean hasNext();
}
```

Then you can instantiate a List this way:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>()
```

Where you might imagine that List stands for a version of List where E has
been uniformly replaced by String:

```
public interface StringList{
  void add(String x)
  Iterator<String> iterator();
}
```

Comment: There's not necessarily any object being instantiated. (Using a reasonable guess at what the example should have been.)

Comment: Hhmm.. you're right, the replacemente its done at _compilation_ time (but anyway, this will be used to instantiate the object later)

Comment: There needn't be any object instantiation going on at all. The syntax appears to be for generic methods, not generic types. (Technically the questioner's example needs one replacement to get to a valid syntax which could be `public <T> foo() { ... }` which is technically valid syntax for a class named `foo` (or does the compiler complain about not using the generic parameter?).)

Comment: Well, you're right again, I should pay more attention :P. And no, the compiler won't complain about it.

Comment: This is not relevant to my question.

Comment: this answer is much simpler to understand as it has less technical jargon. Thanks